# Cannot run mvn clean

Tags: java, maven

When i run "mvn clean " getting error message like below on windows 7 PC.
i tried re-installing maven still error not solved. All other command except mvn clean is running fine.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringMVC Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.222 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-24T13:02:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\suresh\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.5\maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom: end tag name </head> must be the same as start tag <meta> from line 4 (position: TEXT seen ...<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">\r\n</head>... @5:8)  @ line 5, column 8
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: do you run only mvn clean command? after you create your repo is usally indicated to run it with  -o (offline) switch. Since the new versions are not all the time stable.

Comment: What do you mean by `new versions are not all the time stable`?

Answer (score 8):

Seems like somehow your `clean` plugin got corrupted when downloading. Just delete the `C:\Users\suresh\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.5` directory entirely and retry.